# libpqcrypto installation failure

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, cryptography

I am trying to install libpqcrypto for Python implementation. I am following the details described on the official page here: https://libpqcrypto.org/install.html

For convenience I have copied the commands below:
cc and other compiler tools:

```
apt install build-essential
```

OpenSSL header files:

```
apt install libssl-dev
```

GMP header files:

```
apt install libgmp-dev
```

Python 3:

```
apt install python3 #NOTE! I did not run this as I currently have python 3.8.10
```

Check that df /home/ shows at least 300000 1K-blocks available, and that df -i /home/ shows at least 30000 inodes free. Currently a typical compile-and-test run uses about 200MB and about 15000 inodes.

Download, unpack, compile, test, install
In a root terminal, create a libpqcrypto user:

```
    adduser --disabled-password --gecos libpqcrypto libpqcrypto
```

Run a shell as that user:

```
    su - libpqcrypto
```

As that user, download and unpack the latest version of libpqcrypto:

```
    wget -m https://libpqcrypto.org/libpqcrypto-latest-version.txt
    version=$(cat libpqcrypto.org/libpqcrypto-latest-version.txt)
    wget -m https://libpqcrypto.org/libpqcrypto-$version.tar.gz
    tar -xzf libpqcrypto.org/libpqcrypto-$version.tar.gz
    cd libpqcrypto-$version
    ln -s $HOME link-build
    ln -s $HOME link-install
```

Compile, test, and install (this takes time):

```
    ./do
```

After running `./do` it eventually fails and states:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test", line 512, in <module>
    shutil.copytree('%s/%s/%s' % (compiled,c_,'knownrandombytes'),tmp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 555, in copytree
    with os.scandir(src) as itr:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/libpqcrypto/libpqcrypto-20180314/libpqcrypto-20180314/link-build/obj-20180314/mackslaptop/clang_-fPIC_-Wall_-march=native_-mtune=native_-O3_-fomit-frame-pointer_-fwrapv/knownrandombytes'
```

I am runnung this on a python 3.8.10 virtual environment in an ubuntu WSL. However I have encountered this same error on a different ubuntu machine with python 3.10 as well.

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this or find more info on what to do. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install clang
```

Running "./do" after installing clang solved this issue for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).